# C - program throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a compiler program in C (Ubuntu, gcc) using Jack Crenshaw's tutorial http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/. 
However, its written in Pascal, and I am relatively new to C, so I tried to write one as best as I could.

I need some help. A **segmentation fault** is occuring. See Valgrind's output:

```
==3525== Invalid read of size 1
==3525==    at 0x80484C0: GetChar (in /home/spandan/codes/Compiler_1)
==3525==    by 0x8048AAD: Init (in /home/spandan/codes/Compiler_1)
==3525==    by 0x8048ACD: main (in /home/spandan/codes/Compiler_1)
==3525==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3525== 
==3525== 
==3525== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3525==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==3525==    at 0x80484C0: GetChar (in /home/spandan/codes/Compiler_1)
==3525==    by 0x8048AAD: Init (in /home/spandan/codes/Compiler_1)
==3525==    by 0x8048ACD: main (in /home/spandan/codes/Compiler_1)
```

I will post part of the code here relevant to Valgrind's stack trace. The rest can be found at: http://pastebin.com/KBHyRC1n.

Please help with an explanation. According to me all pointers are correctly used. I want to provide command-line input to this program, but even if I don't, its still segfaulting.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static char *Look;
static int LookP = 0;
//read new character from input stream
char GetChar(){
char x;
x= Look[LookP];
LookP++;
return x;
}

// initializer function
void Init(char *c){
Look=c;
GetChar();
//SkipWhite();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv){
Init(argv[1]);
//Assignment();
if (Look[LookP] != '\r'){
   // Expected('Newline');
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be getting a compiler warning about the call to `Init`. It expects `char *` but `argv[1]` is just `char`.

Comment: You should also tell us how you invoke your program, especially what are the command line parameters.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't even get time to input the command line parameters. In windows, the pop up console closes before I can, in linux, it doesn't matter, I give or don't any parameters, it says "segmentation fault, core dumped".

Comment: @Barmar: Surprisingly I am not getting a warning from `Init`.  However, If you see my entire program from the link I provided, I am getting lots of `warning: makes pointer from integer without a cast` throughout my program. However, its definitely getting stuck at `GetChar()` it seems. What might be the problem?

Comment: @Spandan It's best to run your program from an actual command line to use command line parameters. Following MikeCAT's recommendations in [his answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36055350/539810) should also have fixed at least some of your issues.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: I followed MikeCAT's instructions. It didn't work. I also tried running in Linux command line, I am giving my parameters, I am even calling `Init()` with a static string for testing purposes, but no, it still shows `segmentation fault`.

Comment: Your main problem: You did not initialize `token` before writing into it. Also, `if (c==' ' || c=='  ')` → `if (c==' ')`, `if (c>=0 && c<=9)` → `if (c>='0' && c<='9')`

Comment: Your actual code seems too long to debug here. Please use a debugger and try to debug it by yourself. I would appreciate it if you would post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MikeCAT: Please bear with me if I suddenly turn up after a few days and disturb you again. Your answer below and other people's tips have given me something to work upon. Atleast, `segfault` is not happening now. I will surely update this question and get back to you if my problems continue. :) Thanks.

Comment: I'm following the guide you linked, and the translation of returned strings in Pascal to C is one potential stumbling block, which explains your code having a bunch of issues. For example, `char *GetName(char *s, size_t max)`, (e.g. `char name[256]; printf("\tMOVE %s(PC),D0\n", GetName(name, sizeof name));`). You need to ensure that no more than `max` characters are written. Personally, I just typed `if (i+1 >= max) Abort("identifier too long");` at the start of the loop and added a null terminator after the loop ends.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `main()` is wrong. it should be `int main(int argc, char **argv){` (add one more `*` before `argv`)

Also you should check the number of command line arguments before using them.

Comment: I don't even get time to input the command line parameters. In windows, the pop up console closes before I can, in linux, it doesn't matter, I give or don't any parameters, it says `segmentation fault, core dumped`. Also, I did as you said to `main()`, however, it didn't help. What do you think is the reason for segmentation fault? Am I doing something wrong in `GetChar()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

- `SkipWhite` is not defined
- the signature of `main` is wrong it should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`
- `Assignment` is not defined
- `Expected` is not defined
- `Expected('Newline');` doesn't make sens, did you mean `Expected("Newline");` ?
- `argv[1]` is NULL if there are no command line arguments and the program will most likely crash.

For specifying a command line argument when you run the program from the IDE, use the appropriate option (in Visual Studio 2015 right click on the project in the solution explorer, choose Debugging and put whatever you want under "Commande Arguments", for other IDEs I don't know).

You should check if the number of command line arguments is wrong, e.g:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    printf("argument missing\n");
    return 1;
  }
  ...
}
```